# Clone template repo into empty repo, zero history

Tags: git

Suppose my organization has a template application that has some barebones functionality common to most products/projects. I'm wondering what's the best way to observe the following flow

1. Create a new git repo with zero history
2. Download the template repo into the output of step 1 (still no history)

The template repo might have branches, history, etc. But for the use case, assume that master branch is static. So when it's downloaded (cloned?) into the new repo, all of the template's history, branches, etc are purged, leaving only the file hierarchy.

Basically, we don't want x branches on one repo, all of which are in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the content; you could do something like this:

```
git init new-empty-repository
cd new-empty-repository
git remote add --fetch template <template-repository-url>
git archive template/main | tar -xf-
git add .
git commit -m 'Start with template content'
```

Or alternatively:

```
git init new-empty-repository
cd new-empty-repository
git remote add --fetch template <template-repository-url>
git checkout -b main $(git commit-tree -m 'Start with template content' template/main^{tree})
```

Comment: Is `--fetch` a shortcut for `--mirror=fetch`? I cannot find it in the docs. Does it work in non-bare repos?

Comment: With Git version 2.41, `man git-remote` shows `--fetch` as an option to `git remote add`. I would need more context to answer your second question (which repository is bare, the template repository or the one you're creating? If the latter, why are you creating a bare repository?).

Comment: I didn't find it in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote, I only found `--mirror=fetch` and the docs says "*This option only makes sense in bare repositories…*" so my question is about the repo create by your `clone` commands.

Comment: `--fetch` is not an alias for `--mirror=fetch`. It means "fetch the remote branches". You can find it in the man page documented as `-f` (`git remote add --help` shows both the short and long version).

Comment: I see, thanks! My Debian stable (12, bookworm) only has `git` 2.39, so not for me.

Comment: I just looked at git 2.39.2 on Debian 12, and `git remote add --help` reports that it supports `--fetch`.

Comment: `git help remote | grep -F -- --fetch` — No output. But `git remote add --help | grep -F -- --fetch` has it. OMG. `git help remote` is the 1st place I ask for help.